# Joining two tables, returning one row for each unique row in the first table

Tags: mysql, join

So, I'm trying to pull data from two tables. I need each unique row in the first table `Tickets` to be a unique row in the result set. Each ticket might have multiple ticket tags associated with it in the `TicketsTags` table.

When I run the following query I get a row for each unique 'tagid':

```
select 
 `Tickets`.`id`,
 `TicketsTags`.`tagid` 
from 
 `Tickets` left join `TicketsTags`
on 
 `TicketsTags`.`ticketid` = `Tickets`.`id`
where 
 `Tickets`.`id` = 1
```

Returns:

```
id | tagid
----------
1  | 1
1  | 2
```

How do I 'append' each tagid as it's own column, or create an array? So I end out with this:

```
id | tag1 | tag2
----------------
1  | 1    | 2
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: They can have different number of tags, hence different number of columns. What would you want to have in such case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it,

```
select `Tickets`.`id`, group_concat(`TicketsTags`.`tagid`) from `Tickets` left join `TicketsTags` on `TicketsTags`.`ticketid` = `Tickets`.`id` where `Tickets`.`id` = 12 group by `Tickets`.`id`
```

Making use of `group_concat` and `group by` returns a comma separated string of each tagid relating to the ticket id.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

```
select 
`Tickets`.`id`,
GROUP_CONCAT(`TicketsTags`.`tagid`) as 'TagsID' 
from 
`Tickets` left join `TicketsTags`
on 
`TicketsTags`.`ticketid` = `Tickets`.`id`
where 
`Tickets`.`id` = 1
GROUP BY `Tickets`.`id`
```